# Find redirects in my user-journey graph (Neo4j) via cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm generating a user-journey graph of a web-application via client tracking. As the tracking goes, I generate nodes (website URLs) with relations between them. These relationships could be "VIA_CLICK" or "OTHER". Every time a user clicks a link, I generate a new website node, connected to the current node "VIA_CLICK". Sometimes a link does not direct the user to the target URL, instead a redirect happens and the user loads a HTML which is not exactly the target URL from the link. In this case this pattern will be saved in the Neo4j DB: (start-website)-[VIA_CLICK]->(link-target)-[OTHER]->(redirected-target).
I want to find all of this redirections, because in this case, I only want to keep the pattern: (start-website)-[VIA_CLICK]->(redirected-target). All redirections have in common that all following nodes of the link-target node are the same url and the relation between them is "OTHER". I'm having a hard time finding out the correct cypher query. Maybe someone here could help me.

Answer (score 0):

Let's create an example data set:

```
CREATE
  (p1:Site {name:1}),
  (p2:Site {name:2}),
  (p3:Site {name:3}),
  (p4:Site {name:4}),
  (p5:Site {name:5}),
  (p6:Site {name:6}),
  (p7:Site {name:7}),
  (p8:Site {name:8}),
  (p1)-[:VIA_CLICK]->(p2),
  (p1)-[:VIA_CLICK]->(p3),
  (p2)-[:OTHER]->(p5),
  (p3)-[:OTHER]->(p5),
  (p4)-[:OTHER]->(p5),
  (p5)-[:VIA_CLICK]->(p6),
  (p7)-[:VIA_CLICK]->(p8)
```

[image: Example graph]

The first part of the query navigates through the redirections, while the second one looks for direct relations.

```
MATCH (source:Site)-[:VIA_CLICK]->()-[:OTHER*]->(target:Site)
OPTIONAL MATCH (target)-[:OTHER]->(next)
WITH source, target, COUNT(next) as countNext
WHERE countNext = 0
RETURN DISTINCT source, target

UNION

MATCH (source:Site)-[:VIA_CLICK]->(target:Site)
OPTIONAL MATCH (target)-[:OTHER]->(next)
WITH source, target, COUNT(next) as countNext
WHERE countNext = 0
RETURN DISTINCT source, target
```

The result looks like this:

```
╒═════════╤═════════╕
│source   │target   │
╞═════════╪═════════╡
│{name: 1}│{name: 5}│
├─────────┼─────────┤
│{name: 5}│{name: 6}│
├─────────┼─────────┤
│{name: 7}│{name: 8}│
└─────────┴─────────┘
```

I am quite sure the query could be simplified.

Also, I am not sure if this fully answers the question – would you like to modify the graph as well, i.e. insert new edges based on the query results?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! This query maps every source to a target by "ignoring" all "OTHER" relations. For example, if I add a Site 9 and merge it this way: (p2)-[:OTHER]->(p9), I have 2 outgoing OTHER relations from 2. This means that 2 does not work like a static redirect. The query would now output the tuples: (1,5), (1,9), ...
Please note that "OTHER" relations can be valid user navigations in my graph. Every time a HTML gets loaded and its url was not "clicked" right before, the ralation is "OTHER". For example if the user enters the url manuelly. I just want to find obvious redirects.

Answer (score 0):

You need test if count of `other` relationships linkTarget is not great then 1:

```
MATCH (startWebsite)-[:VIA_CLICK]->(linkTarget)
OPTIONAL MATCH (linkTarget)-[:OTHER]->(redirectTarget)
WITH startWebsite, 
     linkTarget, 
     collect(distinct redirectTarget) +  linkTarget as testTarget 
     WHERE size(testTarget) < 3
RETURN startWebsite as source, 
       head(testTarget) as target
```